# Getting error in reading file

Tags: java, java-io

I want to read a file having some numbers which is `Account.txt`
And want to save every line to a string of array.
Ex. the file has 3 lines `123\n234\n456`. And String array a has 3 size and 1st array should have 123, second->234 and 3rd->456.
But It is not working.
Thanks in advance.

```
 package javaapplication10;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class JavaApplication10 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String temp = " ";
        FileWriter fw = null;
        FileReader fr = null;
        int a=0;
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println("1) Input new ");
            System.out.println("2) display ");
            System.out.println("3) Exit");
            System.out.print(" Enter your choice : ");
            int choice = input.nextInt();
            switch(choice)
            {
                case 1: System.out.println(" Enter new Account number : ");
                        temp = input.next();
                        try
                        {
                            fw = new FileWriter("Account.txt",true );
                            fw.write(temp);
                            fw.write(System.getProperty( "line.separator"       ));
                            fw.flush();
                        }
                        catch(IOException ex)
                        {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if(fw!=null)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                fw.close();
                            }
                            catch(IOException ex)
                            {
                                ex.printStackTrace(); 
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    break;
            case 2: try
                    {
                        fr = new FileReader("Account.txt");
                        int i = 0;
                        int line =0;
                        while((i = fr.read()) != -1)
                        {   
                            if(i == '\n')
                                line++;
                        }
                        String s[] = new String[line];
                        a=0;
                        i=0;
                        System.out.println("2");
                        for(int j=0; j<line;j++)
                        {
                            while((i = fr.read())!=10)
                            {
                                if(i!=-1)
                                {
                                    System.out.println(String.valueOf(i));
                                    s[j] = s[j].concat(String.valueOf(i));
                                }
                                else
                                    break;

                            }
                            System.out.println(s[j]);
                        }

                    }
                    catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
                    {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch(IOException ex)
                    {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if(fr!=null)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                fr.close();
                            }
                            catch(IOException ex)
                            {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            fr = null;
                        }

                    }
                    break;
            case 3: System.exit(0);
            default: System.out.println(" Wrong Choice !!!");
        }
    }
}


}
```

Comment: What is the error? Please add the stacktrace.

Comment: The value of file is not stored in String array.

Comment: You're reading the whole file to get the amount of lines and then you're trying to read from the same 'FileReader' to read more... How should there be any more stuff to read, if you already read _everything_?

Comment: Use a List instead of an array (because you don't need to know the final size for it) and add these lines in your first "read loop" to that list. Then remove the second loop.

Answer (score 2):

You try to read your file twice. After the first loop:

```
 while((i = fr.read()) != -1)
 {   
    if(i == '\n')
    line++;
 }
```

Your filepointer is at the end of the file. So in your second loop you have no more content to read.

Comment: But how to initialize the String array. Because I need to give size of array.

Comment: After you have count the lines, you can use the method `reset()` to reset the filepointer and than you can read the file again. Or use a more dynamic object like `ArrayList`